# Is it possible to trigger a javascript to run when a particular anchor is selected?

Tags: javascript, html, anchor, hyperlink

Say I have an anchor on a webpage like so:

```
<a name="comegetit"></a>
```

Is there a way of running a javascript if the page is arrived at by a link that lands on this anchor? (e.g. a link like `<a href="http://myawesomewebpage.com/page#comegetit"></a>`). I don't think there is but I would like there to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only expect this one string as the URL anchor:

```
if(window.location.hash == '#comegetit'){
  // Do your stuff.
}
```

If you're doing anything else complex, you can also match `window.location.hash` against a regular expression.

Comment: The hash value returns with #. (ie "#comegetit")

Answer (score 2):

I use Really Simple History (http://code.google.com/p/reallysimplehistory/)

Then, in my code I do something like this:

```
window.dhtmlHistory.create();
window.dhtmlHistory.initialize();   
window.dhtmlHistory.addListener(function(hash){
    // this is where you process your hash and do something special
    // and totally funky
});
```

This even gets fired on the initial page load, if you happen to bookmark a hash tag or whatnot.

Quite useful, and abstracts away all the browser specific B.S. that comes with window.location.hash

Josh

Comment: Thanks. I'll go with the simple window.location.hash solution for now and see if I run into problems. I don't feel like learning another library today.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to act on the onload event and check for the window.location content to extract the fragment identifier... it should work.