# Execute Javascript when link to anchor is used

Tags: javascript, html

How can I execute a Javascript function when a link to an anchor is used?

I have this anchor:

```
<a id="localizacao" onClick="toogleShow('local')">Click here to show hidden content</a>
```

The user can click on this anchor to show hidden content but I would like to automatically show the content when the user clicks this link that is in another page:

```
<a href="info.html#localizacao"><img src="dcc.png" alt="Localização" title="Localização"></a>
```

Comment: When the page loads, look for a url hash. If there is a url hash, find the element with that ID and click on it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to trigger a javascript to run when a particular anchor is selected?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535605/is-it-possible-to-trigger-a-javascript-to-run-when-a-particular-anchor-is-select)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`window.onhashchange`<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange)

```
window.onload = checkHash;       // page load
window.onhashchange = checkHash; // local click

function checkHash () {  
    if (location.hash === '#localizacao') {  
        toogleShow('local'); // <-- do stuff here  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Will that event be triggered when the page loads? Because the OP is talking about clicking on a link that already contains the hash, from a different page.

Comment: Haven't tested but the [spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html#event-hashchange) implies it won't. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( location.hash === "#localizacao" ) {
    // Do stuff!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a javascript URL check for that anchor to fire when the page loads.

The Browser/HTML alone will only put that anchor into view.  If you want the javascript to act on it, check the URL.  Nevermind, @paislee 's answer is shorter and sweeter.